# How to pass multiple string values through bind variable by comma separated oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

```
SELECT a.gl_account, g.gl
    from et_bp_gl_account a,et_bp_gl g
    where a.gl_id=g.gl_id
    and g.gl in (select replace(:P117_GL,':',',')  from et_bp_gl )
```

----- Here is the code that I use to **pass multiple values through the bind variable like that (Asset Mg:Finance)** the subquery supposed to return (**Asset Mg,Finance**) by replacing ':' by ',' but it doesn't work and returns

> no date found
>
> Using Oracle Sql

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisem  I am using Oracle sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apex, eh? That's either a shuttle item or a select item that allows multiple selection. Anyway, you should split that colon-separated list into rows, something like this:

```
SELECT a.gl_account, g.gl
from et_bp_gl_account a,et_bp_gl g
where a.gl_id=g.gl_id
and g.gl in (select regexp_substr(:P117_GL, '[^:]+', 1, level)
             from dual
             connect by level <= regexp_count(:P117_GL, ':') + 1
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for regular expression

```
select * from table(apex_string.split('1:2:3',':'));
```

So your query might look like

```
SELECT a.gl_account, g.gl
from et_bp_gl_account a,et_bp_gl g
where a.gl_id=g.gl_id
and g.gl in (select column_value
             from table(apex_string.split(:P117_GL,':'))
            )
```

It wouldn't surprise me if this could be simplified further

Comment: Note, this method will perform faster, given a larger delimited list.